# Equality of $C^\infty$-functions on a complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $(M,\Omega)$ be a **compact** Kahler complex manifold of dimension $n$ and let $f,g:M\to \mathbb C$ be two $C^\infty$ functions with the following two propewrties:

1. $\int_M f\Omega=\int_M g\Omega$
2. $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}(f)=\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}(g)$. Where $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}$ is the usual $\bar{\partial}$-Laplacian  constructed by the Hodge $\star$ operator. (However here I suppose that it is enough to assume that $\partial\bar\partial f=\partial\bar\partial g$)

> How can I conclude from the above hypotheses that $f=g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\Delta_{\bar\partial} (f-g) = 0$, this implies that $f-g$ is harmonic and thus constant by compactness. The first condition then implies $f=g$.